# Fastest way to take ownership of a huge amount of files in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, ownership

I've taken 8 TB of drives from my old PC and attached them to my new one, and I no longer have permissions to read/write to many if not all of the folders on most drives. The issue is, I have a huge amount of files on these drives to due an abundance of `node_modules` folders.

I tried taking ownership via Windows Explorer, as well as:

```
cacls E:\ /T /E /G /C Everyone:F
```

These take an inordinate amount of time, and I have no idea how many days it'd take to run this to completion on all of my drives.

Is there a faster way to override the permissions on my files?

I was thinking maybe there's a way to run cacls on multiple threads at once or, since I'm using the same Microsoft account, maybe convince Windows I still have permissions to these files?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Unless these span multiple drives, it is the drive itself that slows down your problem. If the files have a certain usergroup already attached to it with proper permissions, you may be able to get instant access to them by giving yourself membership of that group.

Comment: As an update to the running cacls (I left it running in the bg), it complained about "The data area passed to a system call is too small". Guessing it'd have something to do with the amount of files not fitting in allocated memory? Could you explain a bit what you mean about the groups? I'm not great on non-unix perms.

Comment: By default, user files and folders give `Full control` access to both the System and Administrators account and security group respectively which, in turn, should give you `Full control` access from another computer, provided that your account is a member of the Administrators group, which it no doubt is. It sounds like you may have some non-default, somewhat restrictive permissions on your drives. I would personally just let Explorer take as long as it needs to in order to take ownership of everything. These sound like HDDs, not SSDs, so this drive performance is an unavoidable bottleneck.

Comment: Yeah, it's a worst-case scenario of sorts. The permission situation might be unusual because the drives have been passed down through at least 3 machines and countless Windows re-installs, and now I'm running them over USB in a caddy with 5 drives. If you could imagine a worse situation, it'd be commendable :)

Comment: The good news is that your PC is going to do all of the work for you, you can just set it and forget it. You want to start the process on each of the five drives at the same time, as doing them one at a time will slow the whole process down unnecessarily. The bottleneck is the HDD random seek times, not something related to your PC's resources, so the PC is perfectly capable of taking ownership/resetting permissions on all of the drives at once, if they're all connected.

Comment: All of them are connected over 1 cable, so I'm not actually sure whether it'd be faster to do them separately or not? Not that that matters when I'm gonna leave it overnight :) Thanks for the help

Comment: The bottleneck is the drives' random seek times, not the USB interface. The USB cable has much more bandwidth than you need as only a tiny amount of data is actually be read/written here. The problem is that the heads have to jump all over the platters, touching 8 TB of mostly tiny files. This all comes down to the hardware of the HDDs themselves being relatively slow for this sort of task. It would probably be around 5x faster to do them all simultaneously! You may want to look at your CPU in Task Manager while this is happening to see just how little of your PC's resources this uses.

Comment: "Not that that matters when I'm gonna leave it overnight." Of course it does. If you run them one at a time and do them overnight, it would take 5 nights because you wouldn't be able to start the next drive until the following night. If you started them all at the same time, they would all finish during the first night. That's a difference of 4 days, which is significant because you were asking about the "fastest way" to do this and noting that it was taking an "inordinate amount of time."